# How to remove line, that drawn with brush, without removing image

Tags: html5-canvas, erase, konvajs, brush, react-konva

I have using https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Free_Drawing.html this first example,but also added image in stage.
But when I erase drawn line, image also removed.
How can I fixe that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo is using `globalCompositeOperation = destination-out` to implement erase function. `globalCompositeOperation` affects all drawings in a canvas.

To solve the issue you can use another `Konva.Layer` at the bottom with your image.

Each `Konva.Layer` has its own canvas element. So it will be not affected by shapes with `globalCompositeOperation = destination-out` in another layer.